# Multiple VMs in Ubuntu Server 20.04

Tags: server, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

Complete noob here on VMs.

I have a good spec (EPYC 7502P 32-Core) Ubuntu 20.04 server where I am not using all the resources for the task I am currently running. Is it possible create multiple VMs within that server where I can run different tasks? I want to **allocate specific** number of *cpus/ram/storage* (single nvme ssd) to that VM and ssh into it remotely. Any guidance will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Yep. Install a hypervisor (I like VirtualBox), and then you can make VMs in that. You can set the amount of storage, RAM, and CPU for each VM. If you setup an SSH server in the VM, then you can SSH into the VM, too.

Comment: Please have a look at a list of options at the [server docs virt][https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/virtualization-introduction] and subsequent chapters. In addition if you need something less featureful/flexible but for that very easy to use consider trying https://multipass.run/

Comment: Proxmox and unraid might be interesting solutions for you if.you want to handle or serve multiple vms